# Deserialize xml with 2 different XmlElementAttributes into a single array

Tags: c#, .net, xml, c#-4.0, deserialization

So this maybe some what of a random request but any help would be greatly received!
I am working on an XML document which is something like this...

```
<images>
    <image>
        <url>
            http://www.someUrl.com
        </url>
    </image>

    <bonusimage>
        <url>
            http://www.someOtherUrl.com
        </url>
    </bonusimage>
</images>
```

What I was trying to do was the following:

```
[XmlArray("images")]
[XmlElementAttribute("image", Type = typeof(CustomImageClass), IsNullable = false)]
[XmlElementAttribute("bonusimage", Type = typeof(CustomImageClass), IsNullable = false)]
[XmlChoiceIdentifierAttribute("ItemsElementName")]
public CustomImageClass[] items;

[XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable = false)]
[XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
public ImageType[] ItemsElementName;
```

I also have a enum defined like:

```
[XmlType(IncludeInSchema = false)]
public enum ImageType
{
    [XmlEnumAttribute("image")]
    CustomImage,
    BonusImage,
}
```

I was trying to follow the second scenario on the following web page which describes my issue.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlchoiceidentifierattribute(v=vs.95).aspx

However running this code results in the following error:

Ambiguous types specified for member 'items'.  Items 'bonusimage' and 'image' have the same type.  Please consider using XmlElementAttribute with XmlChoiceIdentifierAttribute instead.

Sorry about the massive post but I have been banging my head against a wall for a while now and wanted to give as much info as possible! I guess I need a second pair of eyes just to help me see where I am going wrong.

Thanks again!

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think you can achieve this.  That looks like it is supposed to be an "either-or" choice, not an all inclusive one.  Unfortunately, I think your best bet is to have two set only fields to have the xml deserialized into and then have a single get only field which concatenates Image and Bonus Image into an array/List/whatever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so thanks for your input, but unfortunately I need to keep the order of the objects. So this is what I found to be the solution:

```
[XmlArray("images")]
[XmlElementAttribute(Type = typeof(Bonusimage))]
[XmlElementAttribute(Type = typeof(CustomImageClass))]
public CustomImageClass[] items;


[XmlType("bonusimage")]
public class Bonusimage: CustomImageClass
{

}

[XmlType("image")]
public class CustomImageClass
{

}
```